# To create a function that receives an integer and returns an NxN 2-D array in spiral format

Tags: javascript, arrays

To create a function that receives an integer and returns an NxN 2-D array in the spiral format as below.

```
1   2   3   4
12  13  14  5
11  16  15  6
10  9   8   7
```

**For example:** if user input 4 then it should return 4*4 2-D array in a spiral format.

I've written below code but it is just user-defined array and I don't know what to do next.

```
//User defined array
var inputArray = [];

for(var i = 0; i < size; i++) {

    //Taking Input from user
    inputArray[i] = prompt("Enter Element " + (i+1));
}

//Print the array in the console.
console.log(inputArray);
```

**Answer:**
javascript

```
var maxSize = 5, itr = 1;
var sri = 0, eri = maxSize - 1, sci = 0, eci = maxSize - 1;
var spiral[][];

/* Variable description
 * --------------------
 * sri - starting row index
 * eri - ending row index           [maxSize - 1, Because array index start from 0]
 * sci - starting column index
 * eci - ending column index        [maxSize - 1, Because array index start from 0]
 * itr - Iterator                   [initialized value can be anything within range of var size]
*/  

//Outer loop to iterate Numbers.
while(itr <= maxSize*maxSize){
    //The movement from left to right. [Row]
    for(var i = sci; i <= eci; i++)
        spiral[sri][i] = itr++;

    //The movement from top to bottom. [Column]
    for(var j = (sri+1); j <= eri; j++)
        spiral[j][eci] = itr++;

    //The movement from the right to left.
    for(var i = (eci-1); i >= sci; i--)
        spiral[eri][i] = itr++;

    //The movement from bottom to up.
    for(var j = (eri-1); j >= sri+1; j--)
        spiral[j][sci] = itr++;

    sci++; eci--; sri++; eri--;
    //Starting  column index should be increase
    //Ending    column index should be decrease
    //Starting  Row index should be increase
    //Ending    Row index should be decrease
}

//Display Spiral Matrix
for(var i = 0; i < maxSize; i++) {
    for(var j = 0; j < maxSize; j++) {
        console.log(spiral[i][j]+ "\t"); //give tab space
    }
    console.log("\n"); //New Line
}
```

Comment: Code added, Yes it is my homework ;)

Comment: Um, whats your question then?

Comment: `var spiral[][];` will give a syntax error, if it's javascript. Have you tested your solution?

Comment: getting syntax error at var spiral[][];